# Entry level propositional logic simplification

Tags: boolean-logic

This is an entry level propositional logic question.

An exercise's final 2 statements are:

(A v B) v (B v C)

A v B v C

Is the last statement a distributive simplification? I can't figure out how the last statement was arrived at.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: If we're combining A&B & B&C then we end up with A&B&C. I'm not sure if it's a `distributive simplification` but I'd guess yes. [1,2,3] v [3,4,5] = [1,2,3,4,5] if I remember correctly.

Comment: Consider the 2 possible values of B and what they will make the statement evaluate to in each case:

`(A v True) v (True v C) = ?`
`(A v False) v (False v C) = ?`

Answer (score 2):

So first use the associative property

(A v B) v (B v C)

can be written like this

A v (B v B) v C

because the associative property will hold.

The idempotent law states that B v B = B

So we end up with

A v B v C

Comment: I was not sure if I had to OR the enter first clause against the second clause. Thank you @Rson1234